# Upgrading from 16.04 to 18.04 breaks i915 driver detection

Tags: 18.04, gpu-driver, intel-nuc, i915

I recently upgraded from **xenial** (`16.04.3 LTS`) to **bionic** (`18.04.3 LTS`), and my intel graphics driver is no longer detected.

I used to use `i915_bpo` as the driver, as far as I remember. And now the module gets detected, but doesn't get associated with the graphic card.

```
$ sudo lsmod | grep i915

i915                 1937408  0
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
drm_kms_helper        180224  1 i915
drm                   491520  2 drm_kms_helper,i915
video                  49152  1 i915

$ lshw -c video

  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Iris Pro Graphics 580
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:db000000-dbffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff

$ sudo lspci -nnk | grep -A3 -i vga

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Iris Pro Graphics 580 [8086:193b] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Iris Pro Graphics 580 [8086:2064]
    Kernel modules: i915
---

$ sudo inxi -SGx

System:    Host: intel-nuc-pc Kernel: 5.3.0-42-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 7.4.0 Console: tty 0
           Distro: elementary OS 5.1.2 Hera base: Ubuntu 18.04 bionic
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel Iris Pro Graphics 580 driver: N/A bus ID: 00:02.0
           Display: server: X.org 1.19.6 driver: intel unloaded: modesetting tty: 208x59
           Message: Advanced graphics data unavailable in console for root.
```

So, the module is there, the card is there, but the card doesn't want to use the module? After a while of browsing existing issues, I had installed `sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-18.04`, hence the kernel version. It changed nothing from `4.15.0-91`.

Consequently, `Xorg.0.log` shows the following information on the matter:

> ````
> [  1549.630] (II) systemd-logind: took control of session /org/freedesktop/login1/session/_31
> [  1549.634] (--) PCI:*(0:0:2:0) 8086:193b:8086:2064 rev 9, Mem @ 0xdb000000/16777216, 0x90000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x0000f000/64, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
> [  1549.634] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
> [  1549.634] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
> [  1549.635] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
> [  1549.635]    compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 1.0.0
> [  1549.635]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
> [  1549.635] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
> [  1549.635] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
> [  1549.636] (II) Module intel: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
> [  1549.636]    compiled for 1.19.5, module version = 2.99.917
> [  1549.636]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
> [  1549.636]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
> [  1549.636] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Integrated Graphics Chipsets:
>     i810, i810-dc100, i810e, i815, i830M, 845G, 854, 852GM/855GM, 865G,
>     915G, E7221 (i915), 915GM, 945G, 945GM, 945GME, Pineview GM,
>     Pineview G, 965G, G35, 965Q, 946GZ, 965GM, 965GME/GLE, G33, Q35, Q33,
>     GM45, 4 Series, G45/G43, Q45/Q43, G41, B43
> [  1549.636] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) HD Graphics
> [  1549.636] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Graphics
> [  1549.636] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Pro Graphics
> [  1551.659] intel: waited 2020 ms for i915.ko driver to load
> [  1551.664] (EE) No devices detected.```
> ````

Additionally:

```
$ dmesg | grep i915

[   68.810865] snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC0D2: No i915 binding for Intel HDMI/DP codec
```

**/etc/default/grub**:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i915.alpha_support=1 ..."
```

How do I break down this issue?

Comment: remove this `i915.alpha_support=1` from /etc/default/grub.

Comment: It does see the driver now. Thank you! I will check a few more things before marking it as solved.

Comment: this option is deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling `i915.alpha_support=1` from `/etc/default/grub`, `update-grub` and subsequent reboot enabled the driver.

Thanks to [**nobody**](https://askubuntu.com/users/966203/nobody) for the solution.

I have not found, however, the means to knowing why it worked.